# Inheriting from MyClass : UIViewController causes error 'Cannot find interface declaration'

Tags: ios, objective-c

I've got a UIViewController named StreamController. It has a XIB with a UITableViewController in it.

I want to build another slightly different view of this StreamController but use the same code that the original provides, so I've created another controller called Stream2Controller. Stream2Controller inherits from StreamController and has it's own XIB file.

My intent is to have the referencing outlets from the Stream2Controller XIB file point to the StreamController.h file. I'm pretty sure I've been successful at this in the past, but for some reason I'm getting this error:

`Cannot find interface declaration for StreamViewController, superclass of Stream2Controller; did you mean SomeOtherController?`

This error is happening in `Stream2Controller.h`

**UPDATE**: Here's some source

`StreamController.h'

```
@interface StreamViewController : UIViewController
```

`Stream2Controller.h'

```
#import "StreamViewController.h"

@interface Stream2Controller : StreamViewController
```

Suggestions?

Comment: check whether StreamViewController.h is added to your target or not ?

Comment: StreamViewController is added to my target.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like I had a recursive include elsewhere in my project that caused this error.

Not a very intuitive error message though. :)

Comment: +1 your solution was the only thing that helped me! So awesome!! :D